# C# Best Way to run a function every second, Timer vs Thread?

Tags: c#, multithreading, timer

I am currently using a thread to run a function every second in a console application C# is a thread the best way to do it? As I have asked a lot of my friends and they have suggested using a timer not a thread for running something every second? If it is a better option to use a timer how would I go about running a function every second using a timer? I have looked around but I am really unsure if that applies to be and if its the right way of going about it in my own way. So can someone tell me the answer and how I can do it?

So what is the best way to run it every second? Before you answer let me just let you know that this is running every second for like 2 days...
My current thread coding

```
namespace Reality.Game.Misc
{
    using Reality;
    using Reality.Communication.Outgoing;
    using Reality.Game.Rooms;
    using Reality.Game.Sessions;
    using Reality.Storage;
    using System;
    using System.Data;
    using System.Threading;

    public static class JobCacheWorker
    {
        private static Thread jWorkerThread;

        public static void HandleExpiration(Session Session)
        {
             using (SqlDatabaseClient client = SqlDatabaseManager.GetClient())
            {
                Session.CharacterInfo.UpdateWorking(client, 0);
            }
        }

        public static void Initialize()
        {
            jWorkerThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(JobCacheWorker.ProcessThread));
            jWorkerThread.Priority = ThreadPriority.Highest;
            jWorkerThread.Name = "JobCacheWorker";
            jWorkerThread.Start();
        }

        public static void CheckEffectExpiry(Session Session)
        {
            try
            {
                //RunMyCodeHere...
            }
            catch (Exception exception)
            {
                    Console.WriteLine("Exception - JobCacheWorker -> " + exception.Message);
            } 
        }

        private static void ProcessThread()
        {
            while (Program.Alive)
            {
                try
                {
                    foreach (Session Session in SessionManager.Sessions.Values)
                    {
                        if (Session != null && Session.Authenticated && !Session.Stopped)
                        {
                            CheckEffectExpiry(Session);
                            Thread.Sleep(1000);
                        }
                    }
                }
                catch (ThreadAbortException exception)
                {
                    Output.WriteLine("ThreadAbortException - JobCacheWorker -> " + exception.Message);
                }
                catch (ThreadInterruptedException exception2)
                {
                    Output.WriteLine("ThreadInterruptedException - JobCacheWorker -> " + exception2.Message);
                }
            }
         }
    }
}
```

Comment: The main thing to consider is that your current code doesn't actually run every second. if the `CheckEffectExpiry` takes half a second then you will be running it every 1.5 seconds (half a second for the process then 1 second sleeping, and repeat). A timer would let you run a method every second but then you'll need to make sure that if the previous one is still running that you don't start stacking up multiples running at the same time (assuming this is what you don't want). You may want to clarify how important precision is in your "every second".

Comment: Sleep is safer than Timer in this case due to the small delay of 1 Second.

Comment: It depends. If your current approach is working, then you forgot to name why it's not working *good enough*. Also note: `Thread.Sleep` doesn't include time taken by function itself to execute, while `Timer` will give you continuous accurate events. Accuracy is debatable, but `Thread.Sleep` after 1000 iteration will have added (accumulated) inacuracy, while `Timer` will not.

Comment: Im looking at this as a approach of stability.. Wich one is more stable and is more stable when coming to running it?

Comment: After a few days my threading crashes and stops working. Is this normal?

Comment: @AshSimpson: If you are worried about crashing then ask a question about that including whatever error messages you are getting. Clearly it isn't what you want so I'm not sure what you mean by "is it normal?". If you mean is it expected that a program with multiple threads will inevitably crash then no, that isn't expected.

Comment: Yes if it's crashing then it could be due to some bug in your code. What is the nature of the crash?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I'd use a [`System.Threading.Timer`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Threading.Timer%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) because it generally uses less resources than a devoted thread. Here's an example:

```
using System;
using System.Threading;

namespace Demo
{
    public static class Program
    {
        public static void Main()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Starting timer with callback every 1 second.");

            Timer timer = new Timer(callback, "Some state", TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1), TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));

            Thread.Sleep(4500); // Wait a bit over 4 seconds.

            Console.WriteLine("Changing timer to callback every 2 seconds.");

            timer.Change(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2), TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2));

            Thread.Sleep(9000);

            timer.Change(-1, -1); // Stop the timer from running.

            Console.WriteLine("Done. Press ENTER");

            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        private static void callback(object state)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Called back with state = " + state);
        }
    }
}
```

This is a good choice for a Console app. However, you must of course bear in mind that the callback is still being done on a separate thread from the main thread, so you must be careful about synchronising resources and variables shared between the callback and the main thread.

Comment: How would I make this run every second? Im new to C#

Comment: @AshSimpson The line `Timer timer = new Timer(callback, "Some state", TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1), TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));` makes it run every second. Run the code and check the output.

Comment: @MatthewWatson: I'd be interested if you were able to expand on why Timer uses less resources than the thread or is it just as simple as they will both use an extra thread but the timer will only have it exist when running whereas the other will have the thread in existence the whole time?

Comment: @Chris Yes, you are correct - the timer will only reuse/create a threadpool thread to issue the callback, and that thread will be freed when the timer code returns.

Answer (score 7):

you  can take a look at  [System.Threading.Timer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.timer(v=vs.110).aspx) which executes a single callback on  a thread pool  at a regular intervals which make it more accurate than threads. 
Here how your code can look like

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    TimerCallback tmCallback = CheckEffectExpiry; 
    Timer timer =  new Timer(tmCallback,"test",1000,1000);
    Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit the sample");
    Console.ReadLine(); 
}

static  void CheckEffectExpiry(object objectInfo)
{
    //TODO put your code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want the task to run parallel to any current task, then using a thread is not a bad option. Although, since the task is to happen every second, I imagine it is a very small task. In that case, preferably use timer because, lesser code and easier understanding.

To do so, you can refer the System [Timer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer(v=vs.110).aspx) class. It has an example and everything.

But in general, these are the things that you'll be doing:

1. Create an instance of a timer (Preferably, declare it globally and initialize it in Initialize())
2. Set the interval (1 second = 1000 millisecond)
3. Enable the timer
4. Start it
5. Optionally, you can even stop it if you want

Comment: "If you want the task to run parallel to any current task, then using a thread is not a bad option" where do you think the Timer executes the code?

Comment: Normally, since every thing moves in a sequential order, your program tends to wait for a current function to complete before it can proceed further, but with threads, the rest of the program can continue working while the thread completes its given task. That is one of the reasons why exchanging data between a thread and your main program isn't allowed nor recommended.

Comment: @Sanketh.K.Jain: Voo's point is that the timer runs stuff on a separate thread too so this isn't really a point between the two.